# wxPython is not throwing exceptions when it should, instead giving raw error messages

Tags: python, exception, wxpython

I'm coding the menu for an application I'm writing in python, using wxPython libraries for the user interface, and I'm attempting to add icons to some of the menu items.  Because I'm trying to be conscientious about it, I'm trying to limit the damage done if one of the image files referenced doesn't exist, and the most simple method (in my mind) is to use exceptions.

The trouble is, when I link to a file that doesn't exist, an exception isn't thrown.  Instead I get a horrific message box stating:

`Can't load image from <path>: Image does not exist.`

This message is exactly the type of thing I'm trying to stop, but even with the broadest exception catching statement nothing works.

This is a cut down version, taking what seems to be relevant, from what I've written:

```
NewProject = wx.MenuItem(File, -1, "&New Project\tCtrl+N", "Create a new project")
try:
    # raises an error message but not an exception
    NewProject.SetBitmap(wx.Image( <path>  ), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap())
except Exception:
    pass
```

So these are my questions:   What am I doing wrong?  Am I approaching this in the wrong direction, putting too much emphasis on exceptions, when there are other ways around it (though non that seem in my head to be as simple)?  Is this a bug in the wxPython library, since I'm pretty sure it should be throwing an exception even if it's not the best way around it?

p.s. The best a Google search could do was recommend I converted all the images to python code using the `img2py` module that comes with wxPython, but I would prefer to keep the images in image format for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a known issue. [Robin Dunn](http://alldunn.com/robin/) answered it a couple of times: just create your Logging method eg.:

```
dummy_log=wx.LogNull()
```

when the variable `dummy_log` runs out of scope, normal logging is enabled again.

Comment: Ok, thats a start;  It doesn't display the error message any more.  But I can't see how that helps me catch the exception, i.e. do something else if that fails.